# How to determine SQL Server 2008 or above

Tags: sql-server, clr, geography, version-detection

I need to determine programmatically if the database supports the Geography data type and Spatial indexes.  These features were introduced in 2008.  I also need to determine if CLR is enabled as these features rely on it.  What is the most reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 is 10.x

You can use [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) in SQL and query [sys.configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188345.aspx)

```
SELECT
   PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar(20)), 3) AS MajorVersion, 
   value_in_use
FROM 
   sys.configurations
WHERE
   name = 'clr enabled';
```

Edit: added CAST

Comment: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type sql_variant is invalid for argument 1 of parsename function.

Comment: `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` shows what is installed, not the compatibility mode being run.  The software relying on `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` will fail if running in a old compatibility mode that does not support the Geography data type.

Comment: @JackAllan: I can't test this, but msdn says "Running value currently in effect for this option"

Answer (score 2):

parse the following:

```
select @@VERSION

SELECT * FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'clr enabled'

SELECT compatibility_level from sys.databases where name=db_name()
```

like:

```
select
    CASE 
        WHEN LEFT(@@VERSION,25)='Microsoft SQL Server 2008' THEN 'Yes' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS OnSQLServer2008
    ,CASE value
         WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
         ELSE 'Yes'
     END AS [clr_enabled]
    ,(SELECT CASE compatibility_level WHEN 100 then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END from sys.databases where name=db_name()) AS SQLServer2008CompatibilityMode
    FROM sys.configurations 
    WHERE name = 'clr enabled'
```

output:

```
OnSQLServer2008 clr_enabled SQLServer2008CompatibilityMode
--------------- ----------- ------------------------------
Yes             No          No

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Was just looking if there is something that returns a more simple result that @@VERSION - it gives a messy string such as "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)"

Comment: Yes parsing @@version I thought of but as Jon says this could be a bit messy is there a more reliable way to determine the version?

Comment: @Jon Egerton,  @@VERSION is not ideal, so I added in compatibility mode check.  It is more accurate than @@VERSION.  If database is 2008, but running in 2005 mode then Geography data type will not exist.

Comment: What happens when you upgrade to SQL 2012? If you just look for `==2008` the code will break and I'm pretty sure the upgrade advisor won't warn you.

Comment: @M_M, this is just a simple example, you can always use `>= 100` type logic on the compatibility_level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT @@VERSION` which returns a fairly verbose string.

Easier is to look at the DB compatibility level using

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name=db_name()
```

This returns a numeric. Frequent values are such as:

> 80 = SQL Server 2000
>
> 90 = SQL Server 2005
>
> 100 = SQL Server 2008

This has the added benefit of checking that the database on the server is at the required level, not just that the server itself it running a particular system version.

Comment: Is compatibility_level required to be 100 for teh new types?

Comment: I read somewhere (on one of the dozens of blogs) that, while it was available, it wasn't a good idea to use less than 100. Just been looking for the item (2 years later!!) and can't put my hand on it. There can be replication issues between levels but I thought there were other more concrete things than that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned query

```
SELECT
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition,
SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') AS EngineEdition;
```

For the bellow mentioned Versions to find out.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]